# Get list of public repositories on GitHub via APIv4

Tags: github-api

With GitHub's API v3 it is [easy](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories) to retrieve a list with all publicly available repositories . I am looking for a way to do the same operation with API v4.

Based on the [API v4 reference](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/query/) I came up with two attempts:

1. **Use the repository field.** But this field requires the `owner` and `name` arguments.

   ```
   query {
     repository(owner: "", name: "") {
       name
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Search for all repositories.** But the `search` field needs the `query` argument.

   ```
   query {
     search(type: REPOSITORY, query: "") {
       repositoryCount
     }
   }
   ```

Both examples need additional information, which limit the result and are therefore unsuited to my purpose. Is there a way to get a (paginated) list of all public repositories with API v4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "API v4" you are referencing is not the GitHub one, but the GraphQL one. It is not "the next GitHub API version", but a completely different way to make queries.

See "[An Introduction to GraphQL via the GitHub API](https://blog.codeship.com/an-introduction-to-graphql-via-the-github-api/)", which uses [`skevy/graphiql-app`](https://github.com/skevy/graphiql-app), a tabbed interface for editing and testing GraphQL queries/mutations with GraphiQL.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/mikesname/d8abd5bb4f7d775adfc2e33ec123f35f) as well as the [official documentation](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#working-with-variables) suggest the query "`repositories`" is available to list all repos. By default, it is limited to the user repositories.

One possible clue would be, as [in this example](https://platform.github.community/t/most-starred-repositories/3016/2), to search users, and then, for each users, to list "`repositories`".

Test it out in the [`developer.github.com/v4/explorer`](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) (used for "[Building a Useful Query](https://services.github.com/on-demand/graphql/first-query)")

Comment: With this approach I am left with a very similar problem: retrieving a list of all user names. -- My impression was, that the REST API will be deprecated at some point in favor of the GraphQL API, but based on your answer this is not the case.

Comment: @sauerburger no depreciation in sight that I know of: both APIs are for different but complementary purposes.